# SOLVED Selenium: Console js code works but not python -> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) null error clicking on element within iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, expected-condition

My Selenium code logs into a website, then reaches a page with a button that exists within an iframe. Inspecting the element in chrome and using the console of the browser, I found the iframe:

```
iframe = document.getElementById("deputy-app-view1045")
```

Then I found the element and am able to click it:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").click()
```

In my python code, I inserted:

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("deputy-app-view1043").contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").click()')
```

However, the error is `"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null".` :(

[SOLUTION]
FIGURED IT OUT! Simply had to add a 'return' inside the js script! Thanks everyone! OLD VERSION:

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("app-iframe dg-content-box margin-none Report Builder (BETA) ready")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").href')
```

FIXED VERSION:

```
browser.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("app-iframe dg-content-box margin-none Report Builder (BETA) ready")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").href')
```

Comment: why can't you just switch to the iframe using `driver.switch_to.frame("deputy-app-view1043")` and then click on the element `driver.find_element_by_id("csv_download").click()`

Comment: you probably have to wait for it to load

Comment: @supputuri, the error I then get is: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a id="csv_download" class="ml5 btn btn-default cus-report-csv-download nav-download-button" href=""> could not be scrolled into view

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)::

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='deputy-app-view']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#csv_download"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'deputy-app-view')")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "csv_download"))).click()
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:  

(and yes, there is nothing after Message:)

Comment: @AcePash _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.  Check the HTML and traverse upwards and observe if the element is within an <iframe> tag, then you have to switch to the desired `<iframe>` first before clicking the element. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT! Simply had to add a 'return' inside the js script! Thanks everyone!

OLD VERSION: ```browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("app-iframe dg-content-box margin-none Report Builder (BETA) ready")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").href')
```
FIXED VERSION: ```browser.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("app-iframe dg-content-box margin-none Report Builder (BETA) ready")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("csv_download").href')```